# How to leave a specific scroll bar in ScrollPane2

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to leave only horizontal scrolling and the vertical to remove it,here is the code.

```js
    $('#container').jScrollPane({})
```

```css
 #container{
        width: 780px;
        height: 140px;
        border: 8px solid #FFF;
        overflow-y: hidden; 
    }
    .slider{
        width: 1400px;
        height: 400px;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #CCCCCC;
    }
    .section{
        margin:0;
        width:220px;
        float:left;
        margin-right:50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="section">section 1 content</div>
                <div class="section">section 2 content</div>
                <div class="section">section 3 content</div>
                <div class="section">section 4 content</div>
                <div class="section">section 5 content</div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What jScrollPane does?

Comment: Edit your question your snippet has errors!

Comment: it has a reference to JScrollPane which I don't have what does it do

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow-y:hidden` and `overflow-x:scroll` for your container div

Css

```
#container{
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-hidden;
}
```

Comment: You should give some width to your **#container** to horizontal scroll to appear

Comment: please send an example on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Prefer use of 'auto' instead of scroll. In case content fits in the block scrollbar will not appear.

```
#container{
  width: 780px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 8px solid #FFF;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example on the jscrollPane website (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrows.html), just add this style to the container div:

```
.horizontal-only
{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```